# How to create a blur action from a keystroke

Tags: jquery, ajax, blur

I have a form that has fields that update in ajax, so you click on a field and then when you click out of it (blur) it automatically updates. However, I would also like to be able to update a field without clicking out of it, and just by clicking enter. I am not entirely sure how to do this, so far I have

```
$('.clients_name_text').focus(function(){
    $(document).keydown(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 13) {
            ???
        }
    });
});
```

The forms look like this

```
<input client_id="422" class="clients_name_text" type="text" value="name1">
<input client_id="422" class="clients_name_email" type="text" value="email1">

<input client_id="423" class="clients_name_text" type="text" value="name2">
<input client_id="423" class="clients_name_email" type="text" value="email2">
etc....
```

So someone would click on the text field like clients_name_text, and edit 'name1', to 'test1', then I want the field to blur. I already have an ajax function that updates the field on blur. What code should I replace with the ???

Comment: `$(this).blur()` ? [https://api.jquery.com/blur/](https://api.jquery.com/blur/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your help, it helped me work it out, here is the answer:

```
$('.clients_name_text').focus(function(){
    field = $(this);
    $(document).keydown(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 13) {
            field.blur();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[There is a blur event in the jQuery API](https://api.jquery.com/blur/). You can also take a look at the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) for more information about custom events.

```
$('.clients_name_text').focus(function(){
    $(document).keydown(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 13) {
            $(this).blur();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".input").keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        // Do something
        $(this).blur();
    }
});
```